# Adicionar um novo objeto literal em um array de objetos!

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, objetos

Gostaria de adicionar um novo item no meu array de objetos através de um método, mas não sei como fazer.

```
public products: Array<Object> = [
  {prodName: 'product 1', prodElement: 'element 1', prodAttribute: 'Attribute 1', attrValue: 'value 1'},
];
```

Comment: Leonardo na boa, se você não sabe como adicionar um novo elemento em um array, acho que não deveria estar mexendo com Angular. Aprenda Javascript puro (Vanilla) primeiro depois parta para algum framework. Só uma dica!

Comment: eu não sabia como adicionar um objeto dentro de um array.
Mas eu conheço os métodos de um array.
Sou estagiário mano, mas valeu pela dica

Answer (score 4):

products está recebendo um array, dentro do array temos a propriedade .push para adicionar e .splice par retirar, .push vc passa apenas um objeto ou qualquer tipo de primário que esteja no array, no splice vc passa o index e como segundo parâmetro o número de índices a serem retirados.

```
products.splice(indexOf, 'itens a serem retirados a partir do index')
products.push({Objeto da forma como vc quiser inserir})
```

Como JavaScript é fracamente tipado, nao tem problema vc declarar da forma:

```
var products = [];
```

Criando aqui dentro os seus objetos.

```
products.push({'nome':'Sérgio', 'idade':23, 'profissao':'programador angularjs}')
```

Comment: É push() não push[].

Answer (score 1):

O `push` incrementa um novo item ao seu array:

```
this.products.push({prodName: 'product 1'});
```

Talvez você tenha que declarar ele assim para funcionar:

```
public products: any = [{prodName: 'product 1'}];
```

Comment: beleza mano. Vou postar o código dá próxima